# Number of ways to assign 6 jobs with distinct difficulties to 3 computers with distinct processing powers with constraints.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The constraints are as follows:

1. The toughest job must be assigned to the fastest computer, and the easiest job must be assigned to the slowest computer.
2. Each computer must be assigned a task.

Constraint #1 can only be satisfied in $1$ way. So, the question really is asking for the number of ways to assing $4$ distinct task to $3$ distinct computers such that the mediocre computer gets at least one task assigned to it.

Arrange the computers from slowest to fastest. `|...|` denotes $1$ computer, `|...|...|` denotes $2$ computers, and so on. In our case, `|...|...|...|` denotes $3$ computers. Let `o`s denote tasks. We want something like this: `|o|ooo|oo|`. (Computer #1 has $1$ job, Computer #2 has $3$ jobs, Computer #3 has $2$ jobs).

If we disregard constraint #2, the number of ways to arrange `o|ooo|oo` ($8$ symbols representing $8$ distinct entities) is $8!$. Since, due to constraint #1, $2$ jobs have already been assigned to $2$ computers, we need to assign $4$ jobs to $3$ computers such that computer #2 has a job.

In other words, out of the $6!$ total ways of arraning `o|oo|o` we want to subtract ways that match `o||ooo`. For this we can consider `||` to be a single symbol. The number of ways of arranging $4$ `o`s and $1$ `||` is $5!$.

From the above, we see that the answer to our original question is $6!-5!=5!(6-1)=600$.

Except it isn't. The correct answer is $65$.

My questions are:

- What am I doing wrong?
- How to calculate the right answer?

Comment: First of all , stars and bars are used to disperse identical objects into distinct boxes , but your question is dispersing distinct objects into distinct boxes

Comment: If you label the four tasks abcd then a|b|cd and a|b|dc are counted as different arrangements by your method.

Comment: @JW_Hi You're right. I can see the mistakes now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment , your method (stars and bars) is used for dispersing identical object into distinct boxes , but our question is that dispersing distinct objects( jobs) into distinct boxes (computers)

For the simplest way : All situations - unwanted cases

All situations : Dispersing $4$ distinct jobs into $3$ distinct computers , it can be done by $3^4 =81$ ways.

Unwanted case : the middle capacity computer does not have any jobs, then it is clear that dispersing these $4$ jops to the slowest and the fastest computers , and it  can be done by $2^4$ ways.

Then $$3^4 -2^4 =81-16=65$$

Answer (score -1):

Each computer gets at least one job, but the jobs are not necessarily evenly distributed. So,

First, the most and least powerful computers get the highest and lowest priority jobs respectively. The medium computer can then get any of the remaining 4 jobs (4c1 combinations so far).

Then, there are three distinct jobs remaining, and 3 computers which can do them. Each of the three computers could take up to all three of the remaining jobs, or none at all. Each job gets one computer, so the total number of job-computer combinations is 3^3 (27)

I get 27*4 or 108 combinations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).